# How would I pop up text in an article via mouseover?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to take a news article and when someone mouses over a given part of the text (not a blue hyperlink)-

1. (without clicking) a pop-up will come up that has annotations/commentary on the article on that given sentence.
2. Smooth animation, not a dialog box where you have to click to exit.

I've looked around, but can't find a decent example. [Here is an okay one](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-bubble.html).

Any ideas on what to use? jQuery? If so, any good suggestions?

Comment: jQuery isn't a programming language!

Comment: seems like you are just looking for a tooltip? I would google jquery tooltips to see if that fits the bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this [jquery tooltip plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/)

It's very easy to use and since the contents of the tooltip is pure HTML, it's very customizable and flexible.

Instead of writing some example code, i'll point you to the [Demos Page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)

I hope this helps, if you want something more specific, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Create a css class which has some of the properties that you want.

```
.ZoomIt
{
   position:relative;
   z-index:99;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
}
```

And toggle the class on hover event

```
$('yourTextualDiv').hover(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('ZoomIt');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full-featured tooltip plugin, have a look at [Tooltipster](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/). You just reference it in your document, like so...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
```

...and then you can add tooltips in various ways, depending on how complex you want the tooltip to be:

```
<img src="my-image.png" class="tooltip" title="This is my image's tooltip message!" />
```

All it takes to activate it is a little JS block somewhere:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
    });
</script>
```

I'm not affiliated with these guys, but I've heard good things about them. I don't see any reason why you should roll your own.